# How to find a bug in GTK+

Tags: debugging, gtk

What is the best way to hack away a bug in GTK+? The bug in https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=127840 is irritating and I would like to see a working version of it. But there is just so many lines of code so how can I find the correct part of the code? I'm using DDD.

Comment: So this seven year old bug is still in there? Edit: yes, gedit doesn't like a 10M file full of `A`s here, either. But I think it won't be easy to fix.

Comment: Is it irritating since it's a "true" use-case for you, or is it irritating simply by existing? Just curious ...

Comment: It is irritating as my favorite text editor is Gedit, it has the bug such at it can't show a line with 700000 characters on single line and one programming exercise ask to find some best substrings on the original string. Well, I can use some other editor.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you know it's a bug in the text view, so you'd look at gtk+/gtk/gtktextview.c and then start following the source out to other related files.

This particular bug is essentially unfixable though. Each paragraph is rendered as a single PangoLayout and PangoLayout doesn't really support processing only part of a single paragraph.
The best fix might be in GEdit to throw an error or insert line breaks or something.